# Android Studio Failing to Run Tutorial App. Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to Android Studio so please speak clearly when explaining potential solutions, I'm not familiar with this environment.

For some reason when I run a sample app the build always fails with an exception. The Gradle Console always shows the message below at runtime:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":
    {},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

**What is causing the "Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'" error and how can I get Android Studio to let me run my application?**

Comment: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter

android support libraries are added twice

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I got this error when there are 2 or more libraries conflict (same library but different versions). Check your app build.gradle in dependencies block.

Check the libraries, I remembered I encounter this problem when I have more than one module using support-v4 and support-v13. I removed support-v4 and it seems solved my problem.

Go to **File**->**Project Structures**. Check the dependencies of each module.

Comment: I checked my libs folder in C:\Users\Me\StudioProjects\AnimationsDemo\app\libs and all I see is android-support-v13.jar. There are no other projects loaded into studio besides this one

Comment: You should go File->ProjectStructure, and check dependencies of each module.

Comment: Ah sure enough I had a support-v4 in addition to my suport-v13. Thanks for the solution, I wasn't aware that this menu existed.